# How to include a "see" reference for a strongly typed generic in summary?

Tags: c#, xml, summary

In summaries we have access to the "see" attribute which will highlight the given reference in the summary popup or whatever it is called.

However when trying to add a reference to, for example, `List<string>` the only option is `<see cref="List{T}"/>`.

How can I replace the `T` with `string`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it still works but try adding the type in brackets after ```{T}```. ```<see cref="List{T}(string)"/>```.

Comment: @Shawn That's rendered as `List<T>(string)`, as expected

Comment: ``<see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"/>`` or else ``<see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.List`1(System.String)"/>`` would be the obvious ways *if* either was an allowed format (using the explicit syntax rather than the sugar), but there's probably a reason VS disallows the obvious sugared alternative (`List{string}`) in that it does not appear to do anything with the instantiation itself (the tooltip still shows `List<T>`). It depends on whatever's processing the XML doc if this ends up doing something meaningful or treated as a syntax error.

Comment: Arguably there is little to no point to forcing this in any case, as there is no separate documentation for `List<string>` (obviously); the only effect it could possibly have is on the rendered text while still linking to the docs for `List<T>`. It could easily be considered *more* confusing to point readers to the docs for a purportedly specific type when it's really just good old `List<T>`, doing what it does for every `T`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I just think it's prettier to have a "This returns a List<string> of stuffs" rather than "This returns a List<T> of strings of stuffs".

Comment: @J.Doe You can just use `List{string}` for that -- you don't need to use a `<see/>` element

Comment: @canton7: the sugared markup for generic types only works inside such elements. You can still explicitly write `List&lt;string&gt;`, of course, with the drawback that that text is language-specific (the syntax for generics and `string` are specific to C#).

Comment: @J.Doe: documenting what the method returns semantically in the `<returns />` does not require explicitly mentioning the type -- the type is already listed in the documentation and IntelliSense will give the method signature. You can just write that it returns a "list of stuffs", or even just "all stuffs". If you're really keen on mentioning the type, as a compromise, you could write "a `<see cref="List{T}"/>` of `<see cref="string"/>` containing the stuffs". (Obviously this doesn't work so well once you have types with multiple params, like `Dictionary`.)